# PATCHing secrets with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hashicorp-vault

When using PowerShell to patch my secrets, I include this payload:

```
Payload: {
    "path":  "EncId",
    "value":  "MB34Changed"
}
```

for this URI: `https://ourvaulturi/v1/enginename/data/secretname`

This is my PS command:

`$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -ContentType 'application/json' -Method PATCH -Uri $uri -Body $payload`
($header includes my Token and Namespace)
I get a `(415) Unsupported Media Type error`

I even tried the Content-Type `application/merge-patch+json`, used in the curl example on this page: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/patch which resulted in error:
`(400) Bad Request`

I don’t want to use PUT because it overwrites ALL values in my secret and I only want to update a single value.

Any ideas or help here?

**Update.**

Running CLI, I was able to get a completed PATCH using this command:
`vault kv patch /enginename/secretname EncId=MB34Changed`

How can I convert this to a PS Invoke-RestMethod call?
If I change the URI to `https://ourvaulturi/enginename/secretname`,
I get a (404) Not Found.

Comment: `https://ourvaulturi/enginename/secretname` probably gives 404 because you're missing the `/v1` in the path stem. In RFC6902 (linked to in the Hashicorp docs), each sample entry also has an `op` member, so perhaps you just need to update the JSON document to be `{"op":"replace","path":..., "value":...}`

Comment: 1. V1 engines do not support PATCHing and you don't need that in the CLI, so why would it be needed here? Besides, using v1 or v2 still gives 404. 2. The CURL examples I've seen do not have an op member in the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that, yes, v1 and data are required in the URI:
`https://ourvaulturi/v1/enginename/data/secretname`

The Content-Type needs to be set in the header:

```
$header = @{
            "X-Vault-Token"="$($env:VAULT_TOKEN)"
            "X-Vault-Namespace"="$($env:VAULT_NAMESPACE)"
            "Content-Type"="application/merge-patch+json"
        }
```

And the payload needs to be formatted as:

```
$payload = 
        @{"data"= 
            @{"$($value)"="$($newvalue)"}
        } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Then, the Invoke-RestMethod need to look like this:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Method PATCH -Uri $uri -Body $payload`